# X and Y are sets. X is infinity and Y is countable. How can I show that #X=#(XUY)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$\#$ is the cardinality.

I tried to create an injection from X to XUY and another from XUY to X, than, it is possible to proof that there is a bijection between the sets due the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem. But I failed, I was not able to create the injections.

Comment: You mean Schroder Bernstein theorem, I think.

Comment: Yes, I also knows as Schröder–Bernstein or Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein or Cantor-Bernstein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate $Y=\{y_i\mid i<\omega\}$ and fix a countable subset $X'=\{x_i\mid i<\omega\}$ of $X$.

The function $f\colon X\cup Y\to X$ defined by
$$f(z)=\begin{cases} x_{2i} & \text{if $z=x_i$ for some $i$}\\
z & \text{if $z\in X\setminus X'$} \\
x_{2i+1} & \text{if $z=y_i$ for some $i$}\end{cases}$$
is a bijection (if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, but if they are not then the cardinality of the union can only be smaller than that of the disjoint union)